# Do inverse limits always exist in the category of C$^{*}$-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras

I know that direct limit always exist. But if we follow the same proof, constructing the direct product, how do we know the norm is finite？

Comment: Your title seems to contradict the first statement made in your question.  Is your question how do we know that the norm is finite, or whether or not direct limits always exist?

Comment: I mean direct limit always exist, how about inverse limit？

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I thought you were only referring to direct limit.